# Serialization performance of basicHttpBinding, netTcpBinding, protobuff extension

Tags: c#, performance, wcf, protobuf-net

I observe strange performance issues - from three ways of accessing WCF service:

- the **fastest** one is via basicHttp
- netTcp is **slower** and
- netTcp with protoBuff-net formatter is **slightly slower** than basicHttp.

Background: I inherited some complex backend app, doing a lot of calculations and DB access, which is called by backend-part of our frontend (i.e. Browser calls A, A calls B, B gets data from SQL, does some computation, returns it to A, who it turns does some more computations and returns it to Browser).

We are talking about performance of the A <-> B part. Most of the data flows from B to A after receiving request from A.

WCF is self-hosted (for this experiment).

Service is exposed via 3 different endpoints:

- basicHttpBinding with messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8"
- netTcpBinding
- netTcpBinding with protobuf-net

I wrote a dedicated simple client that creates a payload.
It just calls the service using 3 different instances of the same WCF client (one for every endpoint).

Calls are done in the loop (101 iterations), first iteration timing is discarded, times are taken with Stopwatch instance.

Single threaded, synchronous calls, each call starts only after the previous one was completed, and returned entities validated.

Called service (B) does same processing for every call, and returned data is identical for every call and for every endpoint.

Each request has small number of primitive types going from the client to B, then B returns `List<T>` with ~36K entities, each entity has int, 2 strings, 2 datetimes (all fields are non-empty). A lot of strings are repeating (they all belong to some dictionary with ~100 possible values). There are several hundreds items for each int value, datetimes are more or less random.

This client and the called service (and SQL) run on the same computer.
As I can't modify the objects returned from the service, I can't use attribute-driven mode of protobuf-net, and forced to use surrogate approach.

Also, client doesn't reference any actual types from the service B, it works using WCF-generated proxies (so protobuf surrogates map themselves to those generated types).

I expected to be protobuf a fastest one, then tcp with default binary encoder, and then slow text based http based.

Actual times are different (times are averages elapsed times of one request in ms:

- Http - 442ms
- Protobuf - 445ms
- Tcp - 514ms

Exact numbers are slightly different each time, but they have same pattern - Http and Protobuf are more or less same, Tcp is 10-15% slower.

Measurements were done when both client and the service are compiled in Release mode Any CPU and run from command line, on Win10 64 bit with 16G Ram.

Times include also the processing done by B, data fetch from the SQL etc, so they are meaningless per se.

So, anyone has any idea what I am doing wrong, or why Http suddenly became a fastest horse in stable ?:)

Last (and first) time I touched WCF was ~13 years ago, guys who wrote the code weren't WCF experts as well, so may be I am overlooking something obvious.

Comment: To be honest this is difficult to answer without seeing the actual solution (code) you are talking about. Agree with you that this is strange behaviour because TCP should easily be the most performant. If you make the code available it may be possible for someone to help.

Comment: @tomredfern I'll try to reproduce it on the pure test code, disconnected from the actual app, then I'll be able to share that. Anyway, at least it **is** strange. Current HTTP performance isn't too bad, so priority of the task is pretty low, driven mainly by my own curiosity :)

Comment: Quick question, are you re-using the client channel for each call? Or are you disposing then creating the client channel for each call?

Comment: @tomredfern 3 clients are created before the test loop, and are reused.
Also, if you are at it :) can you see if those binding settings are reasonable:
 <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IQueryDrivenAPI" maxReceivedMessageSize="996553600" sendTimeout="01:30:00" />
<binding name="NetTcpBinding_IQueryDrivenAPI" receiveTimeout="01:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00" openTimeout="00:30:00" closeTimeout="00:30:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="996553600" maxBufferSize="996553600" maxBufferPoolSize="9524288" transferMode="Buffered">

Comment: Without code its impossible to say and different bindings have different behaviours, particularly **security** which you need to factor in.   If _"This client and the called service...on the `same computer`"_ and performance is paramount, then I would recommend doing away with WCF completely (because XML SOAP messages are verbose) and use straight-up `local named pipes` because **1)** it avoids the network layer making it faster **2)** runs in Kernel mode making it faster again **3)** use binary messages instead of JSON/XML/SOAP to keep the payload small.  protobuf shoud work with pipes

Comment: @MickyD there is no security. For the test they run on the same PC, I am not sure it will be the scenario for production/POC on the customer premises, and I don't want to choose some technology that ties me to the same node.
Running in kernel mode - do you mean hosting it in IIS by itself does that, or something else should be configured?
Re binary messages - I was under assumption that tcp uses binary formatter by default, and protobuf is definitely binary - this is why I hoped to get a better performance from them.

Comment: No prob.  You probably want to run the WCF service on another computer perhaps for a better comparison.  You can still use named pipes for network.  No no, named pipes as an OS feature runs in Kernel mode as opposed to User mode. Nothing to do with WCF or IIS. Ah yes you are correct about TCP binding being binary by default.  Agree about protobuf

Comment: NetTcpBinding uses transport security by default whilst BasicHttpBinding defaults to no security. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.nettcpbinding.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_ServiceModel_NetTcpBinding__ctor and  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding?view=netframework-4.8#remarks